# Elliptic curves and connected components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, rational-points

Are there elliptic curves of positive rank with two real connected components
in which all the rational points lie only on one component?
Concrete examples are really appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. It is not hard to find an example: Take
$$E \colon y^2 = x^3 - 12 x - 1\,.$$
Then $E(\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z$ and $P = (5, 8)$ is a generator (according
to Magma). Since $P$ is on the component of the identity, all rational points are on that component.

Comment: For my own understanding, why does the latter statement hold? At least at first glance, it's not clear to me that addition 'respects' components; is it just a continuity argument ($P+0$ is, so $P+(1/n)P$ is, so...)?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Not sure if this will satisfy you, but $E(\mathbb{R})$ is a compact real Lie group, so it's real-analytically isomorphic to $S^1\times\Phi$, where~$S^1$ is the circle group and $\Phi$ is a finite group. (For elliptic curves, of course, $\Phi$ has to have order 1 or 2.) Anyway, the connected component of $E(\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to the group $S^1$ in this identification.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki A line that intersects the finite component must intersect it twice, so (by the geometric interpretation of the group law) if P and Q are on the infinite (identity) component then so are P+Q, -P. For E,P above (we're told that) P generates all of E(Q).

Comment: @JoeSilverman, David: Those are both excellent explanations - it's great to get both the group-theoretic and geometric versions; thank you!

Comment: In Joe's argument, all you need to know is that $E(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group; the connected component of the identity is then a subgroup.

Comment: and this is essentially the same as the continuity argument that Steven sketched, which is also valid.